# Passing a value from an angular service to a php file

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm trying to pass the parameter from my angular service to a PHP file

```
function SearchStudent(studentId) {
    return $http.get('app-data/search-student.php',
        {params: { studentId:  studentId }})
          .then(function(response) {
          return response.data;
  });
}
```

Then I try to retrieve that value with the _GET in my php file

```
$studentId = $_GET['studentId'] . "%";
```

The problem is instead of just getting the ID I get {"studentId":"######"}

Comment: It looks like JSON, you can just use json_decode() on it, and after you get an array `echo` it like `$variable['studentId'];`

Comment: @lucasnadalutti Your are correct!!! I fixed the problem by declaring a new variable and assigning it with StudentId.StudentId which got me the value I needed to pass, thank you very much!

Comment: @EnriqueMartinez Glad I could help :) as we found the solution, I turned the comment into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SearchStudent` function is already receiving `{"studentId":"######"}` in `studentId` parameter, thus you are sending `{ studentId: {studentId: '######' }}` to your PHP file.